# What is the best way to bind a two dimensional object array to the grid that is also type safe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, grid, kendo-ui

I have a  [kendo UI Grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html) from Telerik
I want to bind a two dimensional object array to the grid. I work in Visual Studio 2012 in ASP.NET MVC. I have a solution where I use a javascript solution. The datatype for the datasource is a **two dimensional object array**. This is because all the rows and columns need to be dynamic in our solution. Here's the JavaScript code to bind the grid:

```
function createGrid() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetSheetData")';
    $.get(url, { hospitalId: 100, screenCode: "Ledger", revisionId: 1, applicationUser: "TestUser" }, function (result) {
        var columnDefs = result.Columns;
        var data = result.Data;

        // Now, create the grid using columnDefs as argument
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: jQuery.parseJSON(data)
            },
            columns: columnDefs,
            height: 430,
            editable: "incell",
            batch: true,
            sortable: {
                mode: "single",
                allowUnsort: false
            },
            filterable: {
                extra: false,
                operators: {
                    string: { contains: "Contains" }
                }
            },
            scrollable: {
                virtual: true
            },

            navigatable: true
        }).data("kendoGrid");
    });
}
```

And the function to post the grid back to the server:

```
    function saveGrid() {
    var  gridDataArray = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid')._data;

    var url = '@Url.Action("SetSheetData")';
    $.post(url, {
        hospitalId: 100
        , screenCode: "Ledger"
        , revisionId: 1
        , applicationUser: "TestUser"
        , dataGrid: JSON.stringify(gridDataArray)
    }
    , function (result) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    });
}
```

The problem with this method  is dat when we call the code:

```
var gridDataArray = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid')._data;
```

and post the data with:

```
JSON.stringify(gridDataArray);
```

all the items in the stringified object become string types. Even those who are numeric. I want my data to maintain the right datatypes

**Does anyone know how to keep my grid data type safe?** 
Any other solutions that do not contain the JavaScript method are fine as well, as long as it supports a two dimensional object array as a type.

I hope the question is clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am still not sure how is the dimensionality involved - can you post example of data you binding to the grid.

Comment: Any progress with your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) _data is private (as per the _), you should not really be calling that! ds.data() will do the job.

2) the way you retrieving/storing data is not wrong, but I would suggest you to make your life easier and define kendo [Transport](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport) properly :

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    }
                }
```

3) as far as the types are involved, use [model](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.model) allowing you define types.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "ProductID",
      fields: {
       //data type of the field {Number|String|Boolean|Date} default is String
        UnitPrice: {
          type: "number",
          defaultValue: 42             
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Bobby_D_, thank you, that was the answer I was looking for. Setting the fields did the trick!